# Ideal dimensions for MATLAB figures on publications

Tags: matlab, latex, matlab-figure, figure

I am asking a short question because I would like to have some opinions on the ideal dimensions that you require/use for a MATLAB figure in a publication.
I am using a direct built-in function of MATLAB in order to generate a figure with appropriate dimensions but I keep being unsatisfied about the result...
My LaTex text document is : width = 470 inches, height = 720 inches.

What do you think is more relevant ?

Thank you for your attention,

Comment: As long as you choose a vector format for your image, e.g. pdf, the absolute dimensions don't matter - you can just scale it to fit the text width of your document. The harder part is to decide on the aspect ratio. Unless you figure needs some specific ratio, e.g. a map, I'd go with the golden ratio.

Comment: Agree, in latex/pdflatex you can use EPS/PDF figures in `\includegraphics` commands, respectively. LaTeX scales them properly if they are vector graphics. My favourite route is to export the figure as EPS, then use `epstopdf`.

Comment: That's the size of a large lorry or a small ship, I doubt you could be satisfied with the usual parameters. Either go with some very imaginative values, or retouch it with some graphic software

Comment: I would always prefer to redraw the figure using Ti*k*Z as it looks much nicer. There is a tool **matlab2tikz** which can help you make the switch.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to you save your figure using the function `axis tight` and define a function to export all your figures.

I've learned to avoid cropping the figure inside LaTeX to reduce compiling time, and I'm using the function below to export all my graphics. [Complete Description](https://github.com/lucasabdalah/basic-functions/blob/main/figures/savefig_tight.m). It exports figures like this one: [Figure Example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lucasabdalah/Hankel-Matrices/main/matlab/fig/poles_proximity-PoleDistance_vs_Samples-2021-05-14.pdf?token=GHSAT0AAAAAABSERUGTNV7CJWUYMGHX5VYWYUDAWPQ)

```
function savefig_tight(h, outfilename)
    set(h,'Units','Inches');
    pos = get(h,'Position');
    set(h,'PaperPositionMode','Auto','PaperUnits','Inches','PaperSize',[pos(3), pos(4)]);
    print(outfilename ,'-dpdf','-fillpage');
end
```